# Git - New repo allows me to "pull origin main" but cannot commit with "push origin main" and gives an error

Tags: git, github

It's been a minute since I've used git/github, and things seem to have changed a bit.

I set up a new repo on GitHub (with *readme*), then created a matching directory on my computer that I'll be working out of.

Opened the terminal in that matching directory...

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/(username)/(reponame).git
git pull origin main
```

I got a warning about...

```
"Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged."
```

but otherwise the pull worked fine and the *readme* is now in my local directory.

Obviously I have the correct "username" and "reponame" in the commands.

BUT then to make sure all is well, I modified the *readme* and tried to push it to the repo...

```
git add -A
git commit -m "First commit, updating readme"
git push origin main
```

and received the error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/(username)/(reponame).git'
```

Looking at the repo online, there is only one branch: *main*

And in the terminal when I check...

```
git show-ref
```

I get two outputs...

```
5...(redacted)...e refs/heads/master
c...(redacted)...0 refs/remotes/origin/main
```

If I try the command

```
push origin master
```

there is no error, but it creates a separate branch on the repo.

So, needless to say, I'm completely lost and have no clue what's going on.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior locally. If you temporarily rename your global git config (possibly `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git`), do you see the same behavior? Is the remote repository empty, or does it already have content?

Comment: I'm not at my comp right now to try the rename, so I'll try that. The git is empty, except for the readme file. So, technically it isn't empty?

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR: `git branch -m main`

For *your specific case*, the fix is easy: just rename your local branch `master` to `main` and you're good to go from here on using the newfangled names.  Reading the rest of this is optional but should help you avoid future snags.

## What happened (long and optional)

This sequence:

> ```
> mkdir (new-directory); cd (new-directory)
>
> git init
> git remote add origin https://github.com/(username)/(reponame).git
> git pull origin main
> ```

isn't wrong *functionally* but is not what you should generally do; generally you just want to:

```
git clone https://github.com/(username)/(reponame).git (new-directory)
cd (new directory)
```

You can omit the *`new-directory`* name if the directory name you want to make is the same as the *`reponame`*: Git will strip off the `.git` and use that.  The `git clone` command does the `mkdir` and runs the remaining commands in the new directory:

1. [reserved for the mkdir step, which is skipped if you provide an empty directory for `git clone` to use]
2. `git init` [run in the new directory created by or provided for step 1]
3. `git remote add origin url` [using the URL you provided]
4. [reserved for extra `git config` steps, if you use `-c` options]
5. `git fetch origin` (not `git pull`!)
6. `git switch branch`, where *`branch`* is from your `-b` option.

This six-step process is really what `git clone` is all about.  The `git init` step makes the new, empty repository databases *in* that empty directory, creating a hidden `.git` directory to hold them.  The `git remote add` step saves your URL for future use, and step 5, the `git fetch`, has your Git software call up the Git software that answers at the saved URL and copy over all the *commits* from that repository.

At this point in the process—at the end of step 5—you have all of their *commits* and *no branches at all*.  The `git fetch` step did see all of their branch names, but made *remote-tracking names* in your databases, instead of making branch names.  This is fine for *Git*, since Git can work without any branch names at all, but not so good for *humans*, who like branch names.  So we move on to step 6, a `git checkout` or `git switch` that *creates one branch name*.

The branch name that step 6 creates is going to be spelled the same as some branch name that the cloned repository has.  If they—the `origin` repository—have multiple branch names, you can choose *which one* using the `-b` option.  Most people don't bother with the `-b` option at `git clone` time, though.  In this case, your Git software asks their Git software which *name* the other repository recommends.

GitHub give you a way to set this, per GitHub repository.  GitHub, like Git, call this the *default branch*.  In the old days, this defaulted to the name `master` for a newly-created GitHub repository, but now it defaults to the name `main`.  Because people don't supply `-b` options to their `git clone` commands, it's sometimes important to know which name some GitHub repository is going to have as its "default branch" setting.  That's the name they are going to recommend, and due to a slight flaw in Git, they'll recommend that branch name *even if that branch name does not exist*.

#### The empty Git repository dilemma

A Git *repository*—as distinguished from a checked-out working tree, which holds ordinary files that you can work on / with—is, at its heart, just two databases.

- One, usually much bigger, holds Git's *commit objects* and other supporting objects.  These store the commits, which *are* the history in the repository.  Each commit, found by an *object ID* (OID) or more colloquially, a *hash ID*, stores a full snapshot of every file, frozen in time as of the form it had at the time you, or whoever, made the commit; and each commit also stores some *metadata*, or information about that particular commit.  These pieces of information combine to link the commits to each other.
- A second, separate database holds *names:* branch names, tag names, and all other forms of names.  Each name stores exactly one OID (hash ID), and *branch* names in particular always store *commit* hash IDs.  These stored hash IDs evolve over time.

The hash ID stored *in* any given branch name is, by definition, the *last* commit that is to be considered "on the branch".  Making a *new* commit, then, consists of making a commit whose parent is whatever commit is *currently* the last one, then changing the stored hash ID *in* that branch name to hold the new commit's new hash ID.

These definitions mean that if we have no commits at all, there are no hash IDs, and therefore there cannot be any *branch names* either.  A branch name *must* hold the hash ID of some existing commit.  With no commits, there are no such hash IDs.

Nonetheless, to *use* Git—to have the ability to create files to `git add` and then run `git commit`—we *must be "on" some branch*.  So when we run `git init` and it creates a new, totally empty pair of databases, we have a dilemma: **there cannot be any branches, and yet we must be "on" some branch.**

Git solves this [Gordian knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot) the way Alexander supposedly did, by just hacking it to pieces.  Git decrees that the *current branch name*—the branch we're "on" when we work in a Git repository—is the *name stored in the special name `HEAD`*, and that *`HEAD` can contain the name of a branch that does not exist*.

So after `git init`, we're "on" a non-existent branch!  That branch simply *springs into being* when we make our *first* commit.  The commit we make is a *root commit*—a commit with no parent commit, which is special in several ways—and the new commit, like any new commit, gets a new, unique hash ID.  Now that there is a commit in the *objects* database, there's a valid hash ID to store in a branch name, so Git now creates the branch name in the *names* database, storing that hash ID into the name in that database.

#### GitHub's role in all of this

When you make a new repository *on* GitHub using their web interface, GitHub give you the opportunity to make a repository that contains the initial, somewhat-special root commit.  This eliminates the dilemma: there's now a commit, so there can be a branch name.  It also means that you can have some initial files, such as a README and/or a license and/or copyright and/or initial `.gitignore`: whatever files you like, you can put in (provided GitHub give you a template with them).

You *can*, if you choose, make a totally-empty GitHub repository.  When you do that, they now set the recommended ("default") branch name to `main`.  They used to set that to `master`, in the old days.  *It is up to you to make sure that you create this branch!*

(I suspect most people take up the "make an initial commit for me" offer, but I have no actual statistics on this.  They—GitHub—would have to do the statistical analysis.)

#### What you did

You:

- had GitHub create a repository with an initial commit, which had some hash ID which they stored under the name `refs/heads/main`: branch `main`;
- created your own totally empty repository, with no commits, which was on Git's own default initial branch `master` (full name `refs/heads/master`); and then
- ran `git pull origin main`.

The `git pull` command is mainly a convenience shorthand for running two *other* Git commands:

1. `git fetch`, which gets most of the options and arguments you pass to `git pull`; and then
2. a second Git command: one of either `git merge` or `git rebase`, with some hairy special casing for "pulling into an empty repository".<sup>1</sup>

The `git fetch`, in your case, fetched the initial commit you made on GitHub, under their branch name `main`, creating `origin/main` in your repository as a remote-tracking name.  Note that at this point you *still have no branch names!*

Now your Git ran the second command.  In your case this was `git merge`.  This is where `git pull` produced its warning:

> ```
> "Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged."
> ```

This warning is a little weird, because you don't have "divergent branches" at this point.  In fact, you don't have any branches at all!  But that's the special-case handling kicking in.  The non-existent branch you're on, `master`, that has no commits, is "divergent" from the existing, single-commit "branch"<sup>2</sup> whose first, last, and only commit is now listed under the name `origin/main` in your repository.

Nonetheless, `git merge` was able to "merge" their `main`—your `origin/main`—with your `master`.  This *created your branch name `master`*, identifying the same *commit* as their branch name `main`—your `origin/main`.

If we draw the commits in your repository, we just have the one commit, the one you cited as `c...(redacted)...0`.  Your Git finds this one commit using the name `origin/main`—really `refs/remotes/origin/main`, which is its full name, but humans normally shorten these, and Git will do that sometimes, depending on which Git command you use.

Because the special-case code now works (and has since Git 1.7 at least), this didn't destroy any work, and instead *checked out* the files from the one commit that you now have.  And now you have your branch, named `master`, identifying the same commit as "their" (your GitHub repository's) branch, named `main` in the GitHub repository.

From here on, things are pretty straightforward: you modified the `README` file, added, and committed.  That made a new commit, `5...(redacted)...e`, whose parent is the initial commit, and stored the new commit's name in the name `master` (`refs/heads/master`), in your names database.

---

<sup>1</sup>This special casing was broken in early Git versions (1.5.something, maybe even 1.6.something) and I was badly burnt at least once.  That's one of the reasons I started avoiding `git pull`—which turned out to be a good thing, as it's by doing separate fetch and second-command sequences that one learns how Git works!

<sup>2</sup>I put quotes around the word "branch" here as `origin/main` is not a *branch name*, it's a *remote-tracking name*.  Is it a "branch" though?  That depends on what we mean when we say "branch": [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

---

#### The fix

If you now *rename* your `master` to call it `main` instead:

```
git branch -m main
```

you end up with:

```
A    <-- origin/main
 \
  B   <-- main (HEAD)
```

where the letter `A` stands in for the initial commit's hash ID, and `B` stands in for your new commit `5...(redacted)...e`.  Commit `B`'s parent is `A`, and you can therefore `git push origin main` to send commit `B` *to* your GitHub repository, where they will add it to *their* `main`, so that your Git updates your `origin/main` in *your* names database:

```
A--B   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

and all is well.

You can also, at any time now—before or after pushing—set the *upstream* setting of your branch name—now `main` because of your `git branch -m` command—to the string `origin/main`.<sup>3</sup>  You can do this with a separate `git branch --set-upstream-to` command, or you can even do it together *with* your `git push` as `git push -u origin main`.

---

<sup>3</sup>The `git branch --set-upstream-to` command and similar commands work with strings like this.  For historical reasons, though, the configuration *in* the `.git/config` file is broken into two parts: a *remote* and a *branch*.  The mapping here is complicated, though if you use all the defaults,<sup>4</sup> it *seems* simple: we just string together the remote name, `origin`, plus the branch-name-as-seen-on-the-remote, `main`, to get `origin/main`.

<sup>4</sup>There's no reason *not* to use the defaults here.  However, if you set up your fetch mappings weirdly, you can have `origin/funky` as your remote-tracking name even if they call it `main`.  You can then call your (local) branch `winkerbean`, for instance.  This will be stored in your `.git/config` as `branch.winkerbean.remote = origin` and `branch.winkerbean.merge = main`, even though the "upstream" of branch `winkerbean` is now `origin/funky` and `git branch -r` shows you `origin/funky` for origin's `main`.  *Don't do this, you'll just drive yourself crazy.*  But it does actually all work.

---

#### Setting up your Git to make `git init` use `main`

If you like the new world of `main` instead of `master`, or even just aren't stubborn (or whatever) enough to insist on living in the past,<sup>5</sup> you can set up your Git so that when you run `git init`, it puts you on the nonexistent branch name `main` instead of the nonexistent branch name `master`.  This requires *either* a new enough Git, or a little trick, though.

In Git versions 2.28 and later, you can run:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

and you're all set.  If your Git *predates* version 2.28, though, you don't have `init.defaultBranch` (and I think you don't have `--initial-branch=` either).  Here, you can use a simple trick.  When `git init` creates a new, empty repository, you'll be on `master`, but you can change this non-existent branch's name with `git checkout --orphan`:<sup>6</sup>

```
git checkout --orphan main
```

Alternatively, make your first commit—this is required in at least some of these older versions of Git—and then run:

```
git branch -m main
```

to rename the `master` that `git commit` created.

---

<sup>5</sup>But the past is so *comfortable!*  It's all hazy with nostalgia and ... *♪ Can it be that it was all so simple then? Or has time rewritten every line? ♪* No, wait, past, present, future, it's all terrible. [It is best never to have been born. But who among us has such luck? One in a million, perhaps. —Alfred Polgar](https://quotefancy.com/quote/1554608/Alfred-Polgar-It-is-best-never-to-have-been-born-But-who-among-us-has-such-luck-One-in-a)

<sup>6</sup>You can do this with `git switch --orphan` as well, but if your Git is older than 2.28, maybe it's older than 2.23 and you don't have the newfangled `git switch` either.  Note that `git switch --orphan` empties Git's index, while `git checkout --orphan` doesn't, though for this case that won't normally matter.

Comment: I can't say enough how much I appreciate you taking the time to write this all up for me. I've always written code by myself and Git is something I've struggled with. This cleared a lot up for me, so thank you again for the detail and easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but in this situation your local `master` (it seems to me that your local branch is called `master`, not `main`) may not track your remote `main`. Try to do it: checkout to your local `master` and then `git branch -u origin/main`